# Ionic video fullscreen mode

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with JWPlayer and Ionic. I'm using JWPlayer to display my videos and it works fine, but i have a strange bug i don't reach to fix.

When i try to display the video in fullscreen mode, it works ONLY if the video is in a modal dialog. If the video is in a view, (ion-view instead of ion-modal-view), the video tries to go fullscreen, and flickers back to normal mode, like if something is blocking the fullscreen mode. I checked the JWPlayer event 'fullscreen', and when the video is in a view, the fullscreen event is triggered twice, and only once if in a modal view. This bug seems to appears only on android device. I'm using the default code.

Someone has experienced then same problem ? and if yes, there is a fix or a workaround ?

Comment: Just tried to reproduce this as quick as possible, it's working fine for me though: http://play.ionic.io/app/dc767325ac04 However just used the quickest way by using an example embed code - how have you integrated the player? Is it possible to reproduce your problem using the playground? Feel free to modify and save it! ;)